# How to catch error messages inside async functions correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

```
app.get('/someFunction', someFunction);

async function someFunction(req, res) {
  try {
    await functionWithError(parameter);
    res.send('success');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err); //works
    res.send(err); //does not
  }
}

async function functionWithError(parameter) {
  return (result = await query('SELECT * from table where column = ?', [
    parameter,
  ]));
}
```

The error in functionWithError is that 'query' is not defined. In try-catch, catch fires correctly but res.send(err) is blank, however console.log(err) works.

Comment: where have you defined `query`? `query` is a function that should be declared before using it or should import from somewhere.

Comment: @NullPointerException — They haven't; that's the point.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue here is that ReferenceErrors  can't be caught by try/catch and the async keyword is a red herring.

Comment: Seems to be working here. http://tpcg.io/_RMIPEN

Comment: console.log(err) works but not with res.send(err), need to edit in the question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*res.send(err) is blank*"? What value do you receive on the client?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be circular structure to JSON error? I suppose that as I cannot see your `query` function.

Can you also try
`console.log(JSON.stringify(err)) //works` ?

If you got error of `// ⛔️ TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` then it is the circular structure issue, that blocks you just "send" as you cannot send a circular object.

For still wanting to send circular object, refer to: https://github.com/WebReflection/flatted#flatted

Comment: No, a `ReferenceError: query is not defined` does not contain a circular structure

Answer (score 0):

An error object being thrown here, Should use err.name or err.message.

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error